# Dagger2 Basics - Field Injection - Not working

Tags: java, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to do Field Injection using Dagger2. I realize I need to call inject manually in case of method injection. I am primarily trying to inject an Engine for a Car. The Engine is decided at runtime, and injected.

The data goes like this

CarInterface

```
import dagger.Binds;

public interface Car {  

    public void run();
}
```

Car Implementation

```
public class Volkswagen implements Car {

@Inject
public Engine engine;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("About to Run");
        engine.start();
    }
}
```

Engine Interface

```
public interface Engine {
    public String start();
}
```

Engine Implementation

```
public class Ferrari4Cylinder implements Engine {

    @Override
    public String start() {
        return "Ignition----Vroom-- Vroom-- Sweet Purring Sound";
    }
}
```

Car Module

```
public  class CarModule{
    @Provides @Singleton
    Car provideCar(){
        return new Volkswagen();
    }   
}
```

Engine Module

```
@Module
public class EngineModule {
    @Provides @Singleton
    public Engine provideEngine(){
        return new Ferrari4Cylinder();
    }
}
```

Component Class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CarModule.class, EngineModule.class})
public interface MyCarComponent {
    public Car provideCar();
    void inject(Car car);
}
```

Main Method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyCarComponent carComponent= DaggerMyCarComponent.builder().build();
        Car car = carComponent.provideCar();    
        carComponent.inject(car);
        car.run();
    }
}
```

For some reason : 
The Car.run() Method always returns null, as the Engine is never Injected. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Can anybody help out on what is happenning here?

*Update 9/02/2016* : 
I figured out that the following changing the component to point to the actual implementation works as shown below. Not sure why the other one does not, but it helped me move forward on the issue.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CarModule.class, EngineModule.class})
public interface MyCarComponent {
    public Volkswagen provideCar();
    void inject(Volkswagen car);
}
```

Hope this helps folks trying to solve the Field Injection issues in Dagger.

Comment: This code works perfectly fine if the CAR interface is not present. Am I hitting a bug or am I missing a notation?

Comment: i am still unable to understand why it is not working. I made dummy project just like you and field injection is not working in that project. I made the changes you suggested in the last comments to change it to Volkwagen car but still i am unable to run the project successfully. It still gives null pointer exception.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If you can send me the code I can have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you forgot to add the `EngineModule` to the `MyCarComponent`.

In order to do field injection you should add the `@Inject` annotation on the `Engine` in the `Car` class. But it is encouraged to avoid field injection if possible. Instead consider doing this:

```
public class Volkswagen implements Car {

  private final Engine engine;

  public Volkswagen(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
  }

}
```

Then in `CarModule`

```
@Provides
@Singleton
static Car provideCar(Engine engine) {
  return new Volkswagen(engine);
}
```

Also, this way you don't need the `inject` method on the component interface.

Remember to add the `EngineModule` to the component, so that dagger can provide an `Engine`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo. I also found out that if the Car Interface is not present. It works just fine. Will update my question. Did I hit a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "the Car Interface is not present". Can you explain?

Comment: If I change the code to look like this it works    public class Volkswagen  {

@Inject
public Engine engine;

public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("About to Run");

    engine.start();

}    Then change the component class to look like this   public Volkwagen provideCar();
void inject(Volkswagen car);

Comment: That's because the component doesn't know how to provide a Volkswagen object (there's no @Provides annotated method that returns a Volkswagen in any of its modules), it knows how to provide a Car.

Comment: @benji, why is it 'encouraged to avoid field injection' ?

Comment: @divyum maybe it's a poor choice of words and I should have said that we should prefer to use injectable constructors. The thing is that injected fields can't be private and can't be final so the class is slightly less robust than it can be. Not the end of the world but if you can inject the constructor there's no reason to prefer field injection.

Comment: @benji, I would still like to enquire the reason behind it. I am using constructor injection but now I want to inject new element which results in code change across  the pkg but had it been field injection, the change would have been only at single location. Also, consider the clean code policy for 5 arguments in constructor. How is it a good practice or better than field injection? I have already used Guice DI so can related to the complexity here.

Comment: @divyum why are there changes across the package? if you inject the constructor you should only be making changes to the class itself and the module that provides the binding. Are you manually calling the constructor somewhere?
I agree that at some point the constructor may become large, but the tradeoff is that you make your API more open, e.g. a caller may change the injected field by mistake.

Comment: @benji, by across the package I meant the class and the test class. Also, if I have to manually call the constructor somewhere else then yes I will have to make changes at multiple places.

Comment: @divyum since the constructor is injectable you shouldn't call it manually except maybe in modules and a test that directly instantiates the class so there is minimal change required. Again it's a tradeoff, I generally prefer to lock down visibility as much as possible.

Comment: @benji, yes I am referring esp to test cases. Otherwise, I am also following what you have suggested. But I still didn't get why should we prefer constructor injection over field injection?

Answer (score 2):

You need to annotate your Engine field with @Inject. I also believe you'll
need to provide the implemented class (Volkswagen as opposed to just Car) to your inject method.

```
public class Volkswagen implements Car {

  @Inject public Engine engine;

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("About to Run");

    engine.start();
  }
}
```

--

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CarModule.class, EngineModule.class})
public interface MyCarComponent {

  public Car provideCar();
  void inject(Volkswagen car);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I had the EngineModule in but missed it out in the question. Adding the Volkswagen in the Component, actually makes it work. But that forces me to change the provideCar method to return an Volkswagen rathe than a Car. Thats strange, as I thought the entire idea is to navigate the object graph, and figure out dependencies.